# BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisherTrigger - stops after re-enabling bluetooth

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have an UWP application on Windows 10 Phone that runs background task to scan for nearby bluetooth devices and get notifications from supported beacons.
It's more or less implementation of this code:
https://mtaulty.com/2015/10/26/m_15980/
It works correctly, but after re-enabling bluetooth, background task stops being launched (basically until phone restart).
Background task is still registered (`BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks` contains my task).
Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Do you have the same issue on desktop?

Comment: Currently I don't have bluetooth enabled desktop for testing. But after thorough search I found information that it might be known OS bug: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/29378db3-75bc-4a8d-be46-63c3280a1239/uwp-bluetooth-if-user-disables-and-then-again-enables-bluetooth-on-mobile-background-task-on?forum=wpdevelop